# Differentiate Between Zero and Blank in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, rally

I have two excel sheets in a document used to make charts from number estimates. One sheet is a database query via plugin that imports data into excel. When pulling the data from my database, you can see the plugin correctly does not populate blanks with a 0 in columns C and D.
[RallyQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RG18.png)

The 2nd sheet is used to perform calculations in order to make the charts. If you look closely, columns G and H should exactly match C and D from the previous picture, however, excel has added zeros in cells that were blank in the database. The formula used to pull the data from the first sheet is:

```
=IFERROR(AgileCentralQueryResultList[@PlanEstimate],"")
```

I need excel to stop replacing blanks with zeros without removing any true zeros that were correct in the database. All of the answers I've found also remove the true zeros, which will not work.
[Totals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/speIu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your formula a little bit,  A blank cell apparently is not going to produce an error.  so you may want to drop the iferror part of your formula and go with an if.   If you have source cells that contain actual error results then you will need to do a second if.

Option 1

```
=IF(AgileCentralQueryResultList[@PlanEstimate]="","",AgileCentralQueryResultList[@PlanEstimate])
```

Option 2

```
=IF(OR(AgileCentralQueryResultList[@PlanEstimate]="",ISERROR(AgileCentralQueryResultList[@PlanEstimate])),"",AgileCentralQueryResultList[@PlanEstimate])
```

Option 3

```
=IFERROR(IF(AgileCentralQueryResultList[@PlanEstimate]="","",AgileCentralQueryResultList[@PlanEstimate]),‌​"")
```

I would try option 1 first and see if you need to take that extra step for error checking using option 2.

Comment: Excellent. The first one works, except once it gets to a row that doesn't exist in the database, it starts throwing errors, which breaks other things... this was the reason for the error check. I tried option 2 but excel doesn't like it. It says it's missing a parenthesis (which it is) but simply adding it to the end also doesn't work. I need the errors to be passive so the rest of the formulas on the sheet are not affected by it.

Comment: Also, using option 1 seems to have broken another formula, although I cannot seem to find out why. Column I (Grouped) is supposed to give me the number in column H, unless it's blank, then it gives me the number in column G. With your option one, column I is appropriately blank but now my grouped column also shows blank, when it should simply show me whats in G. The formula I use for Column I is:

    =IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(H2),G2,H2),"")

Comment: First things first the missing ) does not go at the end but just before the second ,"".  Its supposed to close off the OR() part of the formula.  I was not using excel when I wrote the equation and as such lost track of my brackets.  Apologies for that.

Comment: ok the problem with your ISBLANK formula, is that a blank cell and a cell containing noting "" are not the same thing.  instead testing to see if the cell is blank, test to see if the cell is "".  I would also drop the iferror [art unless you really need it.  I would go with something like `=IF(H2="",G2,"")`

Comment: using the 2nd option (now that it works) doesn't actually stop the error i mention above. I still get #VALUE! errors as soon as I get to a row that doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: You were correct about my ISBLANK formula... can't believe I didn't catch that one. That is working much better now as well, except that it also has the #VALUE! problem mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

Using all the great changes from "Forward Ed" I was able to add my IFERROR check back to his formula to get it all to be happy again. Thanks a ton Ed, credit goes to you for guiding me.

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(AgileCentralQueryResultList[@PlanEstimate]="",ISERROR(AgileCentra‌​lQueryResultList[@PlanEstimate])),"",AgileCentralQueryResultList[@PlanEstimate]),‌​"")
```

Comment: drop the OR( and the whole ISERROR part.  The iserror was supposed to cover the IFERROR you put back in.

Comment: dropping the OR( section makes the zeros come back for some reason. I did drop the ISERROR without issues though.

Comment: So the option 3 formula I posted above is not working?